# Can someone please explain how this python code is executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
positive = -9
negative = -12
while negative:
    if positive:
        print(negative)
    positive += 3
    negative += 3
```

Can you please explain why this code doesn't go on an infinite loop but instead ends gives the result

```
-12
-9
-6
```

How is this code evaluated by the interpretor? Any help would be really helpful

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/

Comment: Check `bool(-3)` vs. `bool(0)`.

Comment: What about it *do* you understand?

Comment: I have understood it now. I am a complete beginner and kinda dumb. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

While there is no special Python dependence here, and the names are peculiarly ill-chosen, it is simple:

You start with a variable -9, increment it by 3 every round. Since you will reach zero (start value and increment have a gcd > 1, i. e. are not co-prime) you are finished soon.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it go into an infinite loop?

During every every iteration of the while loop, it will print `negative` if it is not 0, and increase `positive` and `negative` by 3, this continues until `negative` reaches 0, and the loop ends.